# method not called in fragment

Tags: java, android-fragments

I am relatively new to java and would appreciate some help. I am trying to use a method(handleSelection method) in a fragment but the method does not seem to work and instead it is highlighted that the method is not used.

```
public class TrendingFragment extends Fragment {



    Song selectedSong;

    public void handleSelection(View view)
    {
        String resourceId = AppUtil.getResourceId(getActivity(),view);

        selectedSong = songCollection.searchById(resourceId);

        AppUtil.popMessage(getActivity(), "Streaming song: " + selectedSong.getTitle());

        sendDataToActivity(selectedSong);
    }

    public void sendDataToActivity (Song song)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlaySongActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("id", song.getId());
        intent.putExtra("title", song.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("artist", song.getartist());
        intent.putExtra("fileLink" ,song.getFileLink());
        intent.putExtra("coverArt", song.getCoverArt());

        startActivity(intent);
    }




    private SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);


        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: what function are you trying to use and where?

Comment: my bad for not stating. I am referring to the handleSelection method

Comment: And where are you using it? you Need to call it from somewhere. Are you calling it from outside of the Fragment? The only Thing that this Fragment does is, that it inflates a view

Comment: yes, there is another activity,PlaySongActivity, which is linked. The purpose of the handleSelection method is that upon clicking on the button , it will link back to the PlaySongActivity. However, since my handleSelection method is not able to be used, my app crashes.

Comment: At the Moment i don't get for what you are using a whole Fragment which only inflates a layout, no functions are called in it. How and where are you calling the function, where is the button shown that calls the function on click?

Comment: This fragment is linked to various other fragments. The button is on this fragment's xml file. My goal is that when that button is clicked, the handleSelection method is activated. So, i am using the onClick for the button to open the handleSelection. However, the handleSelection method is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Comments you Need to implement the functions for the button. I assume the Button is inside the view of the Fragment. This should be your oncreateview function.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trending, container, false);
button = findViewById(R.id...):
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                handleSelection(view);

            }
        });

return v;
```

you Need to implement a button variable inside your Fragment and enter the correct id for your button